# rtk-query typescript for custom queryFn on API endpoint

Tags: typescript, rtk-query

I am using a queryFn inside an API call using rtk-query and I cant figure out why typescript is complaining about the return value of the queryFn -- any help would be much appreciated.

This is a simplified version of my code

```
type Fields = {
  name: string;
  dob: string;
}

const fieldsApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getFields: build.query<{ data: Fields[] }, void>({
      queryFn(arg, api, _, baseQuery) {
        const { featureFlags } = api.getState() as RootState;

        if (!featureFlags?.fieldsEnabled) {
          return Promise.resolve([]);
        }

        return baseQuery({ url: "/fields" });
      },
    })
  })
})
```

We need to bail out of requests if the featureFlag is not set (this works) and the calls to get the data are working correctly -- but typescript is not happy.

Posting the error below

```
Type '(arg: void, api: BaseQueryApi, _: {}, baseQuery: (arg: string | FetchArgs) => MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta>>) => MaybePromise<...> | Promise<...>' is not assignable to type '(arg: void, api: BaseQueryApi, extraOptions: {}, baseQuery: (arg: string | FetchArgs) => MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta>>) => MaybePromise<...>'.
  Type 'MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<unknown, FetchBaseQueryError, FetchBaseQueryMeta>> | Promise<never[]>' is not assignable to type 'MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<{ data: Fields[]; }, FetchBaseQueryError, unknown>>'.
    Type '{ error?: undefined; data: unknown; meta?: FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'MaybePromise<QueryReturnValue<{ data: Fields[]; }, FetchBaseQueryError, unknown>>'.
      Type '{ error?: undefined; data: unknown; meta?: FetchBaseQueryMeta | undefined; }' is not assignable to type '{ error?: undefined; data: { data: Fields[]; }; meta?: unknown; }'.
        Types of property 'data' are incompatible.
          Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type '{ data: Fields[]; }'.ts(2322)
```

Do I need to do an as cast when using the queryFn or something like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I need to do an as cast when using the queryFn or something like that?

Yes.  The types for the redux-toolkit `fetchBaseQuery` are defined in a strict way where the JSON data that is returned from the server has type `unknown` (rather than defining it loosely with `any`).  So you do need to make an `as` assertion.

```
return baseQuery({ url: "/fields" }) as { data: Fields[] };
```

You can get fancier about the return type but `as { data: Fields[] };` will work just fine.

---

You've actually got two other errors here.

A base query returns an object which either has an `error` property or a `data` property.  That is:

```
export type QueryReturnValue<T = unknown, E = unknown, M = unknown> =
  | {
      error: E
      data?: undefined
      meta?: M
    }
  | {
      error?: undefined
      data: T
      meta?: M
    }
```

The value of the `data` property is what you would use as the generic for your endpoint.

Instead of:

```
getFields: build.query<{ data: Fields[] }, void>({
```

It should be:

```
getFields: build.query<Fields[], void>({
```

---

The `queryFn` itself should return that `QueryReturnValue` object with `{ data: Fields[] }`.

So this is not a valid return:

```
return Promise.resolve([]);
```

It needs to be:

```
return Promise.resolve({ data: [] });
```

Or without the `Promise`: (you can return a promise but it's not required)

```
return { data: [] };
```

You could also return some sort of error.

---

Complete working code:

```
getFields: build.query<Fields[], void>({
    queryFn(arg, api, _, baseQuery) {
        const { featureFlags } = api.getState() as RootState;

        if (!featureFlags?.fieldsEnabled) {
            return { data: [] };
        }

        return baseQuery({ url: "/fields" }) as { data: Fields[] };
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you explain the "you can return a promise but it's not required" part? Is it due to the `MaybePromise`?